# How does Earth's thermal radiation into space vary by location and time of day?

Tags: atmospheric-radiation, radiative-transfer

[CHEOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHEOPS) (also [1](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/cheops/cheops-launch-and-operations), [2](https://youtu.be/EAIUJaaVJ9U), 3) is a space telescope recently put in low Earth orbit to look for exoplanets around other stars. It uses a cooled detector array and so uses a heat shield to avoid thermal radiation from the Sun as well as the Earth directly below.

Thermal radiation from the Earth is a significant problem for spacecraft thermal management in low Earth orbit, so it's important to know how much thermal radiation Earth emits into space.

If we use [an average emissivity $\epsilon$ of 0.8](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA18833) and assume a temperature of 0 °C, then using

$$P= \sigma \epsilon T^4$$

where the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) $\sigma$ is 5.67 $\times 10^{-8}$ W m<sup>-2</sup> K<sup>-4</sup> we can estimate it to be about 250 W/m<sup>2</sup>.

But what is it really, and how does it vary (on average) by the type of terrain under a satellite and time of day?

---

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40557/12102) to *For a given 48 hour observing period, what fraction of the celestial sphere is available to CHEOPS?* (originally from [the CHEOPS Red Book ESA/SRE(2013)7
November 2013](https://sci.esa.int/documents/34375/36249/1567259940843-CHEOPS_EST_SCI_RP_001_RedBook_i1.0.pdf)

[image]

Comment: When I think of "local variations of Earth's thermal radiation", I always think of this map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_internal_heat_budget#/media/File:Earth_heat_flow.jpg Then I realise Earth's internal heat is nothing compared to the solar contribution (we're talking mW/m$^2$ here)... But as a solid Earth scientist I couldn't help myself to post it anyway! :)

Answer (score 2):

The yearly average Top Of Atmosphere (TOA) Outgoing Longwave Radiation (OLR) is around 145–345 W/m², as measured by the AIRS instrument:

[image: OLR]
<sup>*Source: [Wikimedia Commons contributors, "File:AIRS OLR.png," Wikimedia Commons, the free media repository](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:AIRS_OLR.png&oldid=213002906)*.</sup>

Now, this is an average that includes both day and night.  How much does it vary?  This depends on the location.  Based on GERB data, a 2007 paper estimates (please pay attention to the thick solid line only):

[image: OLR diurnal cycle]
*Source: Comer, Slingo, and Allan (2007)*

Even in places with a very large diurnal temperature cycle such as the Sahara, the difference between maximum and minimum is only about 10%.  In oceanic areas it is closer to 2%.  That means that if you take the mean (shown in the top figure) and subtract around 1–5% depending on the region (the drier, the more difference) you get a reasonable estimate of the nighttime outgoing longwave radiation.

If you want a more precise estimate, you can always download satellite data and calculate it yourself.

---

Full source for second figure: Comer, Slingo, and Allan (2007), Observations of the diurnal cycle of outgoing longwave radiation from the Geostationary Earth Radiation Budget instrument, Geophysical Research Letters, Vol. 34, L02823, doi:10.1029/2006GL028229